# Call to function's are not responding

Tags: javascript, html

**HTML CODE of the slider**

```
<body>
<button id="l"  onClick="imagem()"><b><</b></button>

<img  id="aaa">

<button id="r" onClick="image()"><b>></b></button>
</body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript Code Of the slider**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var aa = ["im1.jpg", "im2.jpg", "im3.jpg", "im4.jpg", "im5.jpg", "im6.jpg"];
    var a = 1;

    function image(n) {
        a = a + 1;
        imageShow(a);
    }

    function imagem(n) {
        a--;
        imageShow(a);
    }

    function imageShow(r) {
        if (r > aa.length) {
            a = 1;
        }
        if (r < 1) {
            a = aa.length;
        }
        document.getElementById("aaa").src = aa[a - 1];
    }

    imageShow(1); // Call to imageShow function not responding.


    auto(); // Call to auto function not responding.

    function auto() {
        if (a > aa.length) {
            a = 1;
        }
        document.getElementById("aaa").src = aa[a - 1];
        a++;
        setTimeout(auto, 5000);
    }
</script>
```

**Kindly someone help me to figure out this problem. The call to `function auto()` and call to "function imageShow" is not responding.**

Comment: try `setTimeout(auto(),5000);`

Comment: I haven't tried to run any of this, but you are calling auto before declaring what auto is. That will be a problem.

Answer (score 2):

You should call `auto()` function after define it.

```
var aa = ["im1.jpg", "im2.jpg", "im3.jpg", "im4.jpg", "im5.jpg", "im6.jpg"];
var a = 1;

function image() {
    a++;
    imageShow(a);
}

function imagem() {
    a--;
    imageShow(a);
}

function imageShow(r) {
    if (r > aa.length) {
        a = 1;
    }
    if (r < 1) {
        a = aa.length;
    }
    document.getElementById("aaa").src = aa[a - 1];
}

function auto() {
    if (a > aa.length) {
        a = 1;
    }
   document.getElementById("aaa").src = aa[a - 1];
   a++;
   setTimeout(auto, 5000);
}
auto();
```

Comment: It works on my browser. Maybe other codes causes the problem.